How to put icons inside the drop-down in Angular
I have a icon component. Then I have a dropDown component which I have build using ng-select.
Then there is Home page where I want to dropdown to show up.
The dropdown is dynamic, I have created an object in home.component.ts. And the list of dropDown renders from there.
What I want is form drop-down is to have an icon with all of the options in the list.
I have used google icons (svg). Also I'm adding a image of drop-down.
<div class="drop-down-container">
    <div *ngTemplateOutlet="dropDownIcons"></div>
    <ng-select [items]="items"
    [bindLabel]="bindLabel"
    [bindValue]="bindValue"
    [placeholder]="placeholder"
    >
    <ng-template #truck>
        @if(items.icon == 'truck'){
            <app-svg-icons 
            icons="truck"
            icons="setting"
            color="red"
            />
        } @else {
            <app-svg-icons 
            icons="trialer"
            icons="setting"
            color="red"
            />
        }
    </ng-template>

</ng-select>
</div>

<ng-template #dropDownIcons>
    <app-svg-icons 
    icons="truck"
    icons="setting"
    color="red"
    />
    <h1>{{items.icons}}</h1>
    </ng-template>


I have tried to look up the on the internet and what I got to know is that it can be done using ng-template, but I couldn't figure out how.
Someone has similar question here but they want to put a single serach icon and that too from the css. What I want, is that it has to be based on the type I have given to it in the TS file.
